# Are there pitfalls to allowing for a Story with an open ending?

Tags: story, 7th-sea-2e

In 7th Sea second edition, I'm working with one of my players on a Story where their character is to retrieve a stolen item of significant value. He hasn't decided what the character wants to do with the item once retrieved, and I thought of the Story having two alternative endings, of which the player can choose when it's the time:

- The character can return the item to gain the respect of its original owner, who becomes his Patron (3 point advantage)
- The character can sell the item to become Rich (3 point advantage)

It seems to me like a safe way to do it, but are there any unexpected pitfalls in offering the player an open ending like this?

Comment: What if the player (or rather, the character) wants to keep the item?

Comment: @Flo They don't, we discussed that in advance (it's a boring box of valuable trinkets)

Answer (score 2):

This might look like a favoritism.

Having a Patron can be more useful than being Rich (or vice versa) in some situations. While other players have already made a choice in advance, this particular player has a privilege of more convenient ad-hoc choice, which doesn't feel fair to other players. Heavily depends on the players though.